# Why can not I use the pre-increment operator in the `ng-mousemove` in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, event-handling

Why can not I use the pre-increment operator in the `ng-mousemove` in AngularJS?

Here is my code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1 ng-mousemove="++count;">Mouse Over Me!</h1>
    <h2>{{ count }}</h2>
</body>
```

The `count` is not incremented. But as soon as I change the code to the:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1 ng-mousemove="count = count + 1;">Mouse Over Me!</h1>
  <h2>{{ count }}</h2>  
</body>
```

Then the code works just fine. Why does the AngularJS not allow the `++count;`, but allows the `count = count + 1;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng-mouseover` directive evaluates AngularJS expressions which are JavaScript-like but have differences.

From the Docs:

> ## AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions
>
> AngularJS expressions are like JavaScript expressions with the following differences:
>
> - **Context:** JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the global window. In AngularJS, expressions are evaluated against a scope object.
> - **Forgiving:** In JavaScript, trying to evaluate undefined properties generates ReferenceError or TypeError. In AngularJS, expression evaluation is forgiving to `undefined` and `null`.
> - **Filters:** You can use filters within expressions to format data before displaying it.
> - **No Control Flow Statements:** You cannot use the following in an AngularJS expression: conditionals, loops, or exceptions.
> - **No Function Declarations:** You cannot declare functions in an AngularJS expression, even inside ng-init directive.
> - **No RegExp Creation With Literal Notation:** You cannot create regular expressions in an AngularJS expression. An exception to this rule is `ng-pattern` which accepts valid RegExp.
> - **No Object Creation With New Operator:** You cannot use `new` operator in an AngularJS expression.
> - **No Bitwise, Comma, And Void Operators:** You cannot use [Bitwise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators), `,` or `void` operators in an AngularJS expression.

**Note: This is not a comprehensive list of the differences.**

Under the hood, the AngularJS framework has its own [expression parser](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) written in JavaScript which avoids the enormous security risk of using [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). If you want to `eval()` an AngularJS expression yourself, use the [`$rootScope/$scope $eval()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval) method or the [$parse Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse).

As seen in the example, the AngularJS expression parser does not parse the increment (`++`) operator or the decrement (`--`) operator.

The operators which AngularJS supports are:<sup>[1](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js#L52)</sup>

```
+ - * / % === !== == != < > <= >= && || ! = |
```

From the Docs:

> ## Sandbox removal
>
> Each version of AngularJS 1 up to, but not including 1.6, contained an expression sandbox, which reduced the surface area of the vulnerability but never removed it. **In AngularJS 1.6 we removed this sandbox as developers kept relying upon it as a security feature even though it was always possible to access arbitrary JavaScript code if one could control the AngularJS templates or expressions of applications.**

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions)
- [AngularJS $parse Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Security - Sandbox Removal](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/security#sandbox-removal)
- [GitHub Source Code - AngularJS - parse.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js)

Comment: That does not answer my question. I do not see in the docs that the prepend `++` operator is not allowed.